# Can't reach containers with new 1.10 DNS SD

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose

I've been trying the latest RC's for docker and compose for a few days, and finally, today, the new stable versions (1.10 and 1.6 respectively).

The new networking stuff added in 1.9 has been great so far. But since I upgraded to 1.10rc1 (and so far for every RC and stable), containers in the same user defined network can no longer find each other. In fact, they can't even reach the outside world right now.

A quick example, file test_docker/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db1:
        image: mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
    db2:
        image: mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
```

This creates two MySQL containers with the official image. According to the compose docs, a new **testdocker_default** should be created, with both containers automatically connected, which is the case:

```
docker network inspect testdocker_default
[
    {
        "Name": "testdocker_default",
        "Id": "820f702e8e685567e4f1a8638cd9be305e96e37fcd741306eed6c1cf0d54ba02",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {
            "16d5594bdfd11f55d33a207612b8447f6b50ff4be8b42d2313707b06ca618556": {
                "Name": "testdocker_db2_1",
                "EndpointID": "b6d5ff10fba860c01ac7a6508e56c5e116296cd06ea2158c695897e18fcd50ce",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "9b8b885dab3b5012c9663cb97a07af66fbe385f92c69a614a4d56bf85305ec3a": {
                "Name": "testdocker_db1_1",
                "EndpointID": "09e43aef8e14b0e876d47fabe67a3827dc4cea5d44b199113d9ab2678d8ce22a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {}
    }
]
```

Now, the documentation also says that the containers should be able to reach each other through **db1** and **db2**, but this is not the case:

```
root@9b8b885dab3b:/# mysql -h db2 -u root             
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db2' (111)
root@9b8b885dab3b:/# mysql -h testdocker_db2_1 -u root
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'testdocker_db2_1' (111)
```

Additionally, neither container is able to reach the internet, unless I explicitly add Google's DNS to the **/etc/resolv.conf**.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here, because I can't find issues raised by other people, but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks guys!

**Edit:**

To clarify, containers can ping each other through their IP address, but the hostnames are not resolved.

Comment: I recreated your setup exactly - just copied and pasted your yml, even used the same directory - and was able to ping the other containers as well as the Internet. DNS lookup works... and I was able to ping `db2` from `db1`.

Comment: I am working with the final release, though, so perhaps your RC is a bad one? Personally, I have to admit I am not sure quite how this new DNS structure works. I read the Issues and PRs and still am confused.

Comment: To add: `$ docker exec -it testdocker_db1_1 bash
root@4fcd80c16e5d:/# mysql -h db2 -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>`

Comment: @deitch Thanks for testing it! I've been using the stable release today, and getting the same results. But yeah, if you were able to get it running without taking any additional steps it may just be that I have a bad install.

Comment: Happy to spend the few mins spinning it up and testing, if it helps. Do you understand how the new DNS structure works? I get that they wanted to stop messing around with `/etc/hosts` because of corruption, makes sense. But what exactly are they running in the docker engine? How does it know what to resolve? There are different networks at different times.

Comment: Frankly no. I've read the PRs multiple times in the past days and I didn't understand much. Then again, networking is quite far from my comfort zone. [They've updated the docs, if it helps.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)

Comment: I didn't understand the PRs either. Thanks for the docs, I will read them

Comment: Seems like it was a combination of issues from selinux and firewalld. Disabling both made docker behave as expected. Will update when I find a cleaner solution :)

Comment: I look forward to reading the details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This issue was reported on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20026). The suggested workaround for the moment is to **disable firewalld** altogether.

I will update this answer with a better solution to this issue as soon as one is found.

**Edit #1:**

[Pull request solving this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/20060) (tested for Fedora 23). This PR is already merged with master, for anyone wanting to compile Docker from source.

Couldn't find an expected release date, but I'm guessing it will be released as a patch version in the next couple weeks. Will update this answer again with further information when available.

**Edit #2:**

[Docker's 1.10.1 RC](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.10.1-rc1) solves this issue. I'll mark this answer as accepted just to close this topic.